# How to make substring optional Kotlin regex

Tags: regex, kotlin

I am practicing regular expressions in Kotlin and trying to start with a multiline string. However, I am not receiving any matches. I feel like I am doing it right and can't figure out the problem.

Test lines:

```
NAME="SLED"
VERSION="12-SP2"
VERSION_ID="12.2"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 12 SP2"
ID="sled"
ID_LIKE="suse"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sled:12:sp2"
```

I am trying to get the 15 and the 2 out of the `PRETTY_NAME` line. I want to make the substring `SP2` optional in the case that it isn't always there. My code doesn't seem to be finding matches.

Regex:

`private val myRegex = Regex("^PRETTY_NAME=\"SUSE Linux (?:Enterprise )?Desktop (\\d+) (?:SP(\\d+))?", setOf(RegexOption.MULTILINE))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it works:

```kotlin
val text = "NAME=\"SLED\"\nVERSION=\"12-SP2\"\nVERSION_ID=\"12.2\"\nPRETTY_NAME=\"SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 12 SP2\"\nID=\"sled\"\nID_LIKE=\"suse\"\nANSI_COLOR=\"0;32\"\nCPE_NAME=\"cpe:/o:suse:sled:12:sp2\""
val myRegex = Regex("^PRETTY_NAME=\"SUSE Linux (?:Enterprise )?Desktop (\\d+)(?: SP(\\d+))?", setOf(RegexOption.MULTILINE))
val match = myRegex.find(text)
println(match?.groupValues?.getOrNull(1))
println(match?.groupValues?.getOrNull(2))
// => 12
//     2
```

See the [online Kotlin demo](https://ideone.com/MkPlqT).

Check the `text` variable that defines the test string, so that all chars are escaped correctly.

Note I put the space into `(?:SP(\d+))?` group so that the space after `(\d+)` is not obligatory.

Make sure you use `.find()` to search for a match anywhere inside the input string (do not use `.matches()` or `.matchEntire` that require a full string match).

You can also define the MULTILINE option using the inline modifier:

```kotlin
val myRegex = Regex("(?m)^PRETTY_NAME=\"SUSE Linux (?:Enterprise )?Desktop (\\d+)(?: SP(\\d+))?")
```